# Fastest way to retrieve newly registered users' instances in Django web app

Tags: python, django, performance

I maintain a Django based newsfeed/social ranking app. I want to introduce an option that shows **new registrations** on the home page (I define **new** as the last three people to join). My user is a vanilla `django.contrib.auth user`.

My home page utilizes a `ListView` to show some recent user interaction. I'm thinking I'd pass new users in a context variable to my template, and render them there. This question is about how to formulate such a context variable **most efficiently**. I'm thinking I could do something like this:

```
context["fresh_users"] = User.objects.order_by('-date_joined')[:3]
```

From a performance point of view, can I do this faster? Ordering of the latest 3 users returned doesn't matter. I looked into using `User.objects.reverse()[:3]`, but **(i)** I don't know if this is supposed to do it faster than `order_by`, and **(ii)** it didn't return the correct results to me, probably because the User model does not define a default ordering?

Locally, I use `SQLite`, but my production environment is `Postgres`. This is a legacy project, on *Django 1.5* and *Python 2.7*. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this query is particularly slow? On the contrary, this seems by far the quickest way to do it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: As objects in User grow, will this become a bottleneck?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Think about optimizing when it actually becomes an issue. You will likely hit other performance problems first

Comment: I was stung deeply by some unoptimized db calls in my code a couple of days ago. I guess I've become overly-cautious after that experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that you have many more reads than writes, which is reasonable for a public facing website, the biggest performance gain you can get in the lookup is to keep track of the newest users in a separate model:

```
class LatestUsers(models.Model):
    latest_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

This model will keep a list of the latest users that you can put in your context. You should create one, via the admin, or manually:

```
>>> LatestUsers.objects.create()
```

Then you can put it in the context:

```
context["fresh_users"] = LatestUsers.objects.all()[0]
```

To keep track of new users you should connect to the `post_save` signal of your `User` model:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# method for updating latest users
def update_latest_users(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created:
         lu = LatestUsers.objects.all()[0]
         # Limit to maximally track the latest 6 users 
         lu.latest_users = lu.latest_users.order_by('-date_joined')[:5]
         lu.latest_users.add(instance) 

# register the signal
post_save.connect(update_latest_users, sender=User, dispatch_uid="update_latest_users")
```

This way you keep track of your latest users in a separate table and can look them up efficiently, even with potentially millions of users.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the elaborate answer :)